# Time complexity of this following code posted below?

Tags: language-agnostic, complexity-theory

Hey i was just wondering if anyone knew the time complexity of this code? Thank you!

```
int func(int n){ // n>0
    if (n < 2) {
        return 1;
    }else if (n%2 == 0) {
        return func(n/3);
    }else{
        return func(n/3) + n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the worst-case, best-case, or average-case scenario? I am curious about this answer as well. It's been forever, cs.stackexchange.com might be better for this question, not sure.

Comment: complexity is O(log n)

Comment: `func(n/3)` and `func(n/3)+n` leads to same complexity. so the complexity is equivalent to `while (n > 2) { n /= 3; }`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

Answer (score 1):

From a complexity point of view, your function can be seen as:

```
int func(int n) // n>0
{
    if (n < 2) return 1;
    else return func(n/3); //constant division
}
```

As commented Bogdan, time complexity of such function if **O(log n)**.